# windows 8 - where is the session?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am planning to develop something small in windows 8 using HTML/JavaScript project type. I have very basic question. How will i manage the session that who is logged in and what they are doing? This looks kind of absurd question so i will try to give some details of what i have in mind.

```
User opens the app and gets login page.
User enters username/password.
App calls WCF service or WebAPI and validates the user.
```

After the third step, user information has to be kept somewhere because i have to know every time who is the logged-in user so that i can check on every operation that what rights the user has and is he authorized to execute particular operation or not.

Since everything here is HTML/JS, i dont know where should i keep the user login information?

Can someone please throw some light as what am i missing here?

Comment: sounds like standard web forms auth with cookies should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PasswordVault` API to store the password or other secret

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx

Then you can send your auth token with the subsequent request.

Is this what you are asking? Or, I misunderstood it?

Comment: Well, i dont know if you are right or not as i have no idea how will i do that. It sounds like i have to save the token somewhere in the JS.

Comment: @Asdfg you can store the token in `window.localStorage` or `Password Vault` depends on how secure you want it to be. If you are only asking where you should store it, then I guess this will be it. But I don't know how well Metro UI supports Cookies now. There should be a "Cookie Jar" for Metro UI too.